# Extract common html content to separate files for reusing

Tags: html, reusability, github-pages

I have built a website (using GitHub pages) which contains a lot of sub-pages. Almost each one of these pages contains the following same content, e.g. footer part like this:

```
<footer id="content-info" class="container" role="contentinfo">
    ...
</footer>
```

My question is: **how to extract this shared same part out to a separate file for reusing?** Then I can simply somehow include this file wherever I need to contain the footer part. If this is possible, I can easily edit this part once and all pages that contain it will change automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub Pages supports Jekyll, a static site generator. Jekyll uses Liquid templating under the hood. You should be able to leverage the templating even without the static site generation.

Here is more info on Jekyll: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/

To get Jekyll to process with GitHub Pages, you probably need to add a `_config.yml` file. More info on that here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Then once Jekyll is processing your `.html` files, you can use a simple templating syntax to include content form other files.

Example:

```
<!-- html here -->
{% include footer.html %}
<!-- more html here -->
```

This will include the contents of `_includes/footer.html` by default. More info on template includes here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @herohuyontao! I usually format things like that so thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your pretty much right on the money, take the code snippets you want to reuse and save them as seperate files.

Then use

```
<?php include_once ("file location/filename.extension"); ?>
```

to include that file :D

##### html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>content here</p>
<?php include_once ("file location/filename.extension"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

##### include file

```
<p>copyright by me<p>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for me. Is it related to GitHub pages that I use to built my website? Maybe it doesn't support PHP?

Comment: Have you got the main pages saved as html or php. It could just be a matter of the wrong file format. Unless specified with a .php extension I don't think it will work.

Comment: Pages are saved as HTML. GitHub doesn't support PHP, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837990/2589776). Sad news :( Any idea to work around?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have that many options left open to you. I suggest looking at frames. I used to build sites with frames and each frame effectively had a separate page controling it.

Frames I think have been superseded by IFrames so might be worth having a look at them.

Comment: Thanks. I will check on that.

Comment: Did you have any sucess with the frames or Iframes?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply copy the content of the div to a php or html file and call it from each page using

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

That way when you change footer.php it'll update across the site.

Comment: As discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837990/2589776), GitHub doesn't support PHP. Any idea to work around?