# Do GitHub pages support PHP?

Tags: php, forms, github, server, github-pages

Thank you for taking the time to review my request for help.

I've been using `gh-pages` to work on a build for a static site and the server has worked amazing for me throughout the build!

Although I seem to have an issue when submitting my HTML web form to my email through PHP code.  When I submit to the gh-pages server I get this error message saying `*405 not allowed ngix*` I've been digging around to find an answer to this. First I discovered that I did have a few minor errors in my code which I fixed. Then I submitted again to the server with the correct code and still received the same message from the gh-pages server. `*405 not allowed ngix*` this leads me to believe that the gh-pages server does not support any PHP code.

I found some information on SO about the gh-pages server not supporting PHP. [How to publish .php page instead of .html at github to demo some php content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837946/how-to-publish-php-page-instead-of-html-at-github-to-demo-some-php-content)

[image: screen shot 2014-12-27 at 12 44 19 pm]

[image]
[Server side includes alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326742/server-side-includes-alternative)

Does PHP run on gh-pages? Or not?

If not then I know that everything on my side is correct and I should not worry about it because when I truly deploy this site live I'll use a server that does support PHP.

Here's my current build so you can test out my issue.
http://kapena.github.io/pp_web/#contact-pp

This is what I am getting when I submit the form to the server..

[image]

Comment: I'm 90% sure it only supports HTML & JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: @DaryllDoyle yeah that's what I think so to..Just emailed git hub on this issue. Best way to get the answer is just go straight to the source of it :)

Comment: What I've done in the past is to run a github action that commits back you your repo:
Steps:
1. Commit your_page.php to repo
2. action runs php your_page.php > your_page.html
3. action commits your_page.html to repo
4. page is live

this would work with something like php include for headers and stuff, which is exactly what i used it for previously, but not any execution server side.

edit: I used to to it via oneliner in netlify: mv index.html index && php index > index.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A static site cannot by definition support PHP.

- Static websites serve content directly from the web-server’s file-system
  exactly as stored.
- Dynamic websites generate content live per each request. The request is
  delegated to a running web-application that builds the content.

[What is a Static Website](http://nilclass.com/courses/what-is-a-static-website)

You might be interested in [PieCrust](http://bolt80.com/piecrust). It is a
static site generator.

Comment: You might also be interested in [gohugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo)

Answer (score 9):

Github pages currently **do not support PHP** as it only supports static website.

However, if you want to display some **dynamic content** on your website, you can simply use **iframe** to display that content, but again it has to be hosted somewhere else.

Here is something that might be helpful to you:
[Guide to use Github Pages](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/a-guide-to-using-github-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

No, but they do support embedded PHP:
You embed a page into GitHub pages, and the page has PHP hosted on other hosting sites.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean?

Comment: @posfan12 You can embed an iframe of your php site into github pages but you still have to host php somewhere for that