# How can I "redirect" a get request with PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say that I make a get request to `https://example1.com/?data=1234`
Is there any way I can make the server respond with the response from `https://example2.com/?data=1234`?
I'm a complete PHP newbie, and this is my first time using it for something actually meaningful.

EDIT:
I don't want to redirect from `https://example1.com/?data=1234` to `https://example2.com/?data=1234`.
I want to pass the parameters from the original get request to example2.com, it responds, then I send back the response I got to the original get request user.

FOR EXAMPLE:

`GET https://example1.com/api?value=123`

`RESPONSE: 12345`

`GET https://example2.com/api?value=123`

`RESPONSE: 12345`

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: Does Github Pages even support PHP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672315/do-github-pages-support-php

Comment: You want a *reverse proxy*, i.e. a web server which just forwards the request and returns its response. This can be configured via .htaccess directives for Apache for example without any PHP. Or you can write some PHP that makes the request to the remote server and echos the response…

Comment: You dont call the file, you include it in and maybe call a function from it.