# Create json server in github.io

Tags: angularjs, json, github

I made an angularJS application and it runs form github.io. But I need to use REST API to handle data. I use json-server at my localhost. Is it possible to create and use json-server in github?

Answer (score 7):

I know its old question but I'll still post an answer here just in case someone else wants it.

It is possible to have json-server running in Github pages. Here is the link [https://my-json-server.typicode.com/][1]

Basically create a db.json file in your repository just like you do in the local system. you can access your api with https://my-json-server.typicode.com// as your your root URL.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it is not possible because *github.io* only delivers static files and doesn't run any server.

You will need to use another hosting provider to run the *json-server*.

[See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837946/how-to-publish-php-page-instead-of-html-at-github-to-demo-some-php-content)

Comment: Using shared hosting service (like hostgator) will work ? @brclz