# 405 error message when sending a POST request to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm sending a POST request using AJAX like so:

```
var time = Date.now();
request = $.ajax({
    data : 'time=' + time,
    url : '/php/save.php',
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

The save.php file looks as follows:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo $_POST["time"];
?>
```

And the error message I am getting is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

According to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf), the headers I've added should have done the trick. But also, the error itself is a bit confusing because clearly the *save.php* is in **the same domain** as the *index.html* file.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions. Apart from the PHP file configuration I've shown above I've tried many others as suggested by similar questions or answers on Google - no luck so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Try without the headers and amend this `data : 'time=' + time,` to `data : {time: time},`

Comment: Just tried it - still the same error

Comment: Is this a local server or a hosted server

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a hosted server

Comment: Is it a very cheap one? maybe they dont allow POST

Comment: What happens when you visit /php/save.php directly?

Comment: The server is actually github.io. When I visit php/save.php directly it downloads the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish .php page instead of .html at github to demo some php content?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837990/1913729)