# How to update multiple pages by just editing one

Tags: php

I have a header on each page of my website, and as more pages are added, it is increasingly difficult to change all of them. I looked it up, and found that you need to use PHP, using something like include("menu.html");. Is that possible on Github pages. I found out that you need to end the file in .php, but whenever I try to access the page, there is a 404 error.

Ex. blahblah.php

I can't got to that page. How can I get to that page?

Edit: Well, it looks like Github can't do PHP. Is there anyway I can update all my files at once on Github, or any other web hosts that can do that?

Comment: I think you can find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837946.